# Unknown Operation Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this [question:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew8Id.png)

> If $a\otimes b=a^b-b^a$, what is $(3\otimes 2)\otimes (4\otimes 1)$?

The answer in the solution set I was given is $-2,$ but I'm not sure how to get there, and I can't find any sort of similar problems online.  Can anyone explain the process of solving this and how to find more resources for solving these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just plug it in:

$(3\otimes 2)\otimes (4\otimes 1)=(3^2-2^3)\otimes(4^1-1^4)=1\otimes3=1^3-3^1=\;?$

Comment: start with quantities inside parentheses

Answer (score 0):

If the problem had been posed this way:

> Let $f$ be the function with
>
> - domain pairs of positive numbers,
> - range all real numbers, and
> - value at $(a,b)$ given by $$\begin{align} f(a,b) &= a^b-b^a \end{align}$$
>     and suppose that the numbers $u$ and $v$ are given by
>     $$\begin{align} u &= f(3,2) & v &= f(4,1) \end{align}$$
>     What is the value of $f(u,v)$?

Would you be able to solve it?

Comment: I like the way you put this, thanks.